# Segmentation fault after calling initscr(): Ncurses

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I am trying to use ncurses for a program that I am writing and keep getting a segmentation fault. The segmentation fault is happening when I call initscr().

When debugging with gdb it says:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_getenv (name=0x7ffff7fa02ca "RM") at getenv.c:84
84  getenv.c: No such file or directory.
```

When running valgrind it I get:

```
==40905== Invalid read of size 2
==40905==    at 0x4B1CC8D: getenv (getenv.c:84)
==40905==    by 0x487DE40: initscr (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.2)
==40905==    by 0x10A4B4: main (Source.cpp:11)
==40905==  Address 0x7ff0003d4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==40905==
==40905==
==40905== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==40905==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FF0003D4
==40905==    at 0x4B1CC8D: getenv (getenv.c:84)
==40905==    by 0x487DE40: initscr (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.2)
==40905==    by 0x10A4B4: main (Source.cpp:11)
==40905==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==40905==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==40905==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==40905==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==40905==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==40905==
==40905== HEAP SUMMARY:
==40905==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==40905==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 81,426 bytes allocated
==40905==
==40905== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Here is my code:

```
#include "pen.h"
#include <ncurses.h>


int main()
{
    //initscr();
    pen game;
    initscr();
    game.printBaseScreen(1);
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "gameState.h"
#include <ncurses.h>

class pen
{
private:
    //gameState game;
    void printBorders();
    void printOver();
    void printUnder();
    CampainMap map;
    //const OverworldTerrain* getmap() const;

public:
    void printBaseScreen(bool);
    pen();
    ~pen();
};

void pen::printBaseScreen(bool underOver)
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    printBorders();
    if(underOver) {printOver();}
    else {printUnder();}    //auto i = sizeof(OverworldTerrain);
    refresh();
}

void pen::printUnder(){}

void pen::printOver(){}

void pen::printBorders()
{
    printw("+");
    for (int i = 1; i < 199; i++)
    {
        move(0, i);
        printw("-");
        move(53, i);
        printw("-");
    }
    move(0,199);
    printw("+");
    for (int i = 1; i < 53; i++)
    {
        move(i, 0);
        printw("|");
        move(i, 199);
        printw("|");
        move(i, 119);
        printw("|");
    }
    move(2,0);
    printw("+");
    move(2,119);
    printw("+");    
    move(43,0);
    printw("+");
    move(45, 0);
    printw("+");
    move(43, 119);
    printw("+");
    move(45, 119);
    printw("+");
    move(17,119);
    printw("+");
    move(17, 199);
    printw("+");
    for (int i = 120; i < 199; i++)
    {
        move(17, i);
        printw("-");
        move(32, i);
        printw("-");
    }
    
    move(32, 119);
    printw("+");
    move(32, 199);
    printw("+");

    for (int i = 1; i < 119; i++)
    {
        move(2,i);
        printw("-");
        move(43, i);
        printw("-");
        move(45,i);
        printw("-");
    }
    move(0, 119);
    printw("+");

    move(53, 0);
    printw("+");
    move(53,199);
    printw("+");
}

pen::pen(): map()
{
    
}
pen::~pen(){ endwin();}
```

```cpp
enum TerrainType
{
    WOODS, ROCKY, FIELD, SCRUBS, CRAGGY, BUILDING, PASSAGE, UNDERWORLD, DUNGEONWALL, DUNGEONFLOOR
    /* 
    TERRAIN TYPE:
        WOODS = T
        ROCKY = o
        FIELD = "
        SCRUB = .
        CRAG  = ^
    */
};

struct OverworldTerrain
{
    TerrainType type;
    bool buildable;
    bool building;
    bool rubble;
    bool hero;

    OverworldTerrain() : buildable(1), building(0), rubble(0), hero(0)
    {

    }
};


struct UnderworldTerrain
{
    TerrainType type;
    bool hero;
    bool trap;
    int monster;
    int treasure;
    char label;

    UnderworldTerrain() : hero(0), trap(0), monster(-1), treasure(-1){}
};
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "TerrainType.h"

class CampainMap
{
public:
    void Create_Emerald();
    void mapCreator(int);
    void printOverworld();
    void printUnderworld();
    OverworldTerrain getTerrainOverworld(int, int) const;
    CampainMap();
    ~CampainMap();

private:
    OverworldTerrain Overworld[41][57];
    UnderworldTerrain Underworld[41][57];
    int map;
    std::fstream openFile(int);
};
void CampainMap::mapCreator(int mapName)
{
    std::fstream f = openFile(1);
    std::string line;
    
    for (int y = 0; y < 42; y++)
    {
        getline(f, line);
        for(int x = 0; x < 58; x++)
        {
            switch (line[x])
            {
            case '.':
                Overworld[y][x].type = SCRUBS;
                break;
            case 'T':
                Overworld[y][x].type = WOODS;
                break;
            case '"':
                Overworld[y][x].type = FIELD;
                break;
            case 'o':
                Overworld[y][x].type = ROCKY;
                break;
            case '^':
                Overworld[y][x].type = CRAGGY;
                Overworld[y][x].buildable = false;
                break;
            case '0':
                Overworld[y][x].type = PASSAGE;
                Overworld[y][x].buildable = false;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < 42; y++)
    {
        getline(f, line);
        for(int x = 0; x < 58; x++)
        {
            switch (line[x])
            {
            case '~':
                Underworld[y][x].type = UNDERWORLD;
                break;
            case '=':
                Underworld[y][x].type = DUNGEONWALL;
                break;
            case '.':
                Underworld[y][x].type = DUNGEONFLOOR;
                break;
            case '!':
                Underworld[y][x].type = DUNGEONFLOOR;
                Underworld[y][x].trap = true;
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case 'd':
            case 'e':
            case 'f':
            case 'g':
            case 'h':
            case 'i':
            case 'j':
            case 'k':
            case 'l':
            case 'm':
            case 'n':
            case 'o':
            case 'p':
            case 'q':
            case 'r':
            case 's':
            case 't':
            case 'u':
            case 'v':
            case 'w':
            case 'x':
            case 'y':
            case 'z':
                Underworld[y][x].type = DUNGEONFLOOR;
                Underworld[y][x].monster = line[x] - 96;
                break;
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
                Underworld[y][x].type = DUNGEONFLOOR;
                Underworld[y][x].treasure = line[x] - 48;
                break;
            case '^':
                Underworld[y][x].type = PASSAGE;
                break;
            default:
                Underworld[y][x].type = UNDERWORLD;
                //Underworld[y][x].label = 'line[x]';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
}

OverworldTerrain CampainMap::getTerrainOverworld(int y, int x) const
{
    return Overworld[y][x];
}

void CampainMap::printOverworld()
{
    std::string temp;
    for (int y = 0; y < 41; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 57; x++)
        {
            switch (Overworld[y][x].type)
            {
            case WOODS:
                std::cout << " T";
                break;

            case ROCKY:
                std::cout << " o";
                break;

            case FIELD:
                std::cout << " \"";
                break;

            case SCRUBS:
                temp = "\u1427";
                std::cout << " " << temp;
                break;
            case CRAGGY:
                std::cout << " ^";
                break;

            case PASSAGE:
                temp = "\u1401";
                std::cout << " " << temp;
                break;

            default:
                std::cout << "XX";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//TODO: Add way of telling if monster is defeated.
void CampainMap::printUnderworld()
{
    std::string temp;
    for (int y = 0; y < 41; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 57; x++)
        {
            switch (Underworld[y][x].type)
            {
            case UNDERWORLD:
                std::cout << "  ";
                break;

            case DUNGEONFLOOR:
                if (Underworld[y][x].trap)
                {
                    std::cout << " !";
                } else if (Underworld[y][x].monster > 0)
                {
                    char l = Underworld[y][x].monster + 96;
                    std::cout << " " << l;
                } else if (Underworld[y][x].treasure > -1)
                {
                    std::cout << " " << Underworld[y][x].treasure;
                }else
                {
                temp = "\u1427";
                std::cout << " " << temp;
                }
                break;

            case DUNGEONWALL:
                //temp = "\u220E";
                temp = "\u2395";
                std::cout << " " << temp;
                break;

            case PASSAGE:
                temp = "\u1403";
                std::cout << " " << temp;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "XX";
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std:: endl;
    }
}

std::fstream CampainMap::openFile(int mapName)
{
    std::fstream f;

    //Eventually will add more maps
    switch (mapName)
    {
        case 1:
            f.open("./maps/EmeraldCopse.txt", std::fstream::in);
            break;
        default:
            perror("Map does not exist lol");
            exit(2);
    }

    if (!f.is_open())
    {
        perror("File failed to open or not found");
        exit(2);
    }

    return f;
}

CampainMap::CampainMap()
{
    mapCreator(1);
}

CampainMap::~CampainMap()
{
}
```

When I run the above code I get a segmentation fault.  If I move `initscr()` to before `pen game` in main(), there is no segmentation fault. Additionally, if CampainMap is not a variable of pen, then it does not matter where `initscr()` is called.  Which leads me to believe that my problem lies somewhere in CampainMap.    Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: Valid indexes into `Overworld[41][57]` are 0 through 40 for the first index, and 0 through 56 for the second. `CampainMap::mapCreator` accesses `Overworld[41][57]`, whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Always the little things.  That fixed it.  Thank you.